# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet';Access denied for user 'root'@'XXXX'

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I cannot connect to the instance suddenly (I was able to connect a week ago). I tried several ways but none of those worked.
The error messages I got:

Command: mysql --host=[INSTANCE_IP] --user=root --password
Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Command: gcloud beta sql connect [INSTANCE_ID] --user=root
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'XXXX'

Answer (score 0):

That error usually indicates that the password is incorrect. Have you or someone else changed the password on the instance?

Comment: Before I log in, I try changing the password associated with root. However, that still doesn't work.